# Display entire line containing certain characters in Linux

Tags: linux, search

I am wondering if there is a way to display the entire line in a data file containing specific characters in linux? For example searching for "577789999" in a file.txt should display me the line such as below

```
577789999    adef   YTM   777888
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's what `grep` is for

```
grep 577789999 file.txt
```

you might want to restrict the pattern to occur only in the beginning of the line:

```
grep ^577789999 file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you this was precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Generaly, you might use grep like that : 
grep "the researched string" "filename"

It'll tells you at which line you're string is, and if you search it on "*" (All files in the current dir), it tells you in which file you're string is ;)